# Generating hash key for facebook development

Tags: android, hash, android-facebook

I have recently started working on facebook API, where I came under the situation of generating Hash key and registering it on facebook for further use.

For that, I used the following code

```
PackageInfo info;
try {
    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.you.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
        Log.e("hash key", something);
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```

All worked well, as I was able to work with facebook in my app.

But, after publishing the app on playstore, I found the error Invalid_Android_key parameter. The key  does not match any allowed key  Configure your app key hashes at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/..........

Please, let me know the cause of this problem and how to handle this.

Comment: have you changed your bundle id in "com.you.name"?

Comment: yes, I did that. That's why it worked well while debugging.

Comment: Have you hashed your debug key or your key to export the app?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you mean?

Comment: You have two different signing keys, if you run it during development you are signing your app automatically with your debug key, but if you export it and uppload it to the play store you have to generate a new signing key. Facebooks wants the Hash of the signed key uof the app uploaded in play store, but have a look at Sanchit1234s answer

Comment: okay, so does that mean, I have to register the hash-key even for the signed apk together with the one for unsigned apk?

Comment: no just for the signed you upload in play store

Answer (score 1):

I had same Problem, after creating the apk, the key hash is changed! because using this code u get the debug keystore hash, but when creating apk, it's another hash, gotta capture it from log after trying ur apk on emulator , then delete code and export again without this log , i know it's a hassle  but for me it was easier than keytool...

Comment: Okay, I will give it a try.

Comment: If you're using eclipse, I'm pretty sure it lists your hash when you export a signed apk.